# Couldn't select child element

Tags: css, css-selectors

```css
.test .par:first-child .test1 .test2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>testable</p>
  <p class="par">
    This is <i class="test1"> dsd <i class="test2">red</i>text.</i> test
  </p>
  <p class="par">
    This is <i class="test1"> dsd <i class="test2">shouldn't changed</i> text.</i> test
  </p>
</div>
```

In the above code, what i would like to do is to apply a css for the first class **test2** but i couldn't do that.
That css didn't do the thing.
Please help.

**UPDATE**

**NB**: the `p` elements within the parent `div` element are generated dynamically. it means that sometimes there are more `p` elements before the first **test2** element and sometimes the **test2** elements are the first element from the parent.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but the way you indent your code is absolutely horrifying and makes no sense whatsoever

Comment: see this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/47814027/6222075

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.par:first-child` is equal `*.par:first-child` and It means select any element that is first children his parent and have class `per`; so, dont select `<p class="par">` because it is not first children.it is 3nd children so use this:

```
.test .par:nth-child(3) .test1 .test2 {
```

```css
.test .par:nth-child(3) .test1 .test2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="test">
    <p>test</p>
    <p>testable</p>
    <p class="par">
        This is 
          <i class="test1">
              dsd
              <i class="test2">red</i>
              text.
          </i>
        test
    </p>
    <p class="par">
        This is 
          <i class="test1">
              dsd
              <i class="test2">shouldn't changed</i>
              text.
          </i>
        test
    </p>
    </div>
```

**UPDATE:**

If `p` generated dynamically and you only want first `.par` use this:

```
.test .par .test1 .test2 {
  color: red;
} 

.test .par ~ .par .test1 .test2 {
  color: black;
}
```

```css
.test .par .test1 .test2 {
  color: red;
} 

.test .par ~ .par .test1 .test2 {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">

  <p>test</p>
  <p>testable</p>
  <p class="par">
    This is <i class="test1"> dsd <i class="test2">red</i>text.</i> test
  </p>

  <p class="par">
    This is <i class="test1"> dsd <i class="test2">shouldn't changed</i> text.</i> test
  </p>

</div>
```

Comment: @user777 but what if we have more `.par` element and not next to each other ? they are not generated dynamilcy ?

Answer (score 2):

The container `.test` contain 4 `p` elements so the element you are targeting is not the first-child but the **3rd one**. Instead you can do this :

```css
.test .par:nth-child(3) .test1 .test2 {
  color: red;
}

/*
Or simply
.test p:nth-child(3) .test1 .test2 {
  color: red;
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>testable</p>
  <p class="par">
    This is
    <i class="test1">
              dsd
              <i class="test2">red</i> text.
    </i>
    test
  </p>
  <p class="par">
    This is
    <i class="test1">
              dsd
              <i class="test2">shouldn't changed</i> text.
    </i>
    test
  </p>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If the `p` elements are dynamicly generated you will not able to select your `.test2` element with the current HTML structure (unless you are able to change it). We can also consider the use of `nth-of-type` but `.test2` is at the same range in both `p` element.

By the way here is a non-CSS solution if interested with :

```js
$('.par').eq(0).find('.test2').css('color','red');

//to only consider test2 you can simply use :
//$('.test2').eq(0).css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>testable</p>
  <p class="par">
    This is
    <i class="test1">
              dsd
              <i class="test2">red</i> text.
    </i>
    test
  </p>
  <p class="par">
    This is
    <i class="test1">
              dsd
              <i class="test2">shouldn't changed</i> text.
    </i>
    test
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but before i forgot to mention that the P elements are generated dynamically. i edited my post.

Comment: @user777 ah i see :) i think it's faisable with only CSS, but am thinking about that ;)

Comment: @user777 i think it won't be possible in you case, so i added a non-CSS solution if interestesd ;)

Comment: Thanks again @Temani Afif. I have already thought about adding jquery but i thought i could solved it with only css. thank you, i will add javascript code then.

Comment: @user777 with my actual knowledge i am sure we cannot BUT maybe someone else will give us a CSS solution :) and then we will both learn a new thing ;)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.test p:nth-child(3) .test1 .test2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>test</p>
  <p>testable</p>
  <p class="par">
    This is <i class="test1"> dsd <i class="test2">red</i>text.</i> test
  </p>
  <p class="par">
    This is <i class="test1"> dsd <i class="test2">shouldn't changed</i> text.</i> test
  </p>
</div>
```